# How to select and click a button without an id attribute

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" style="font-weight:bold;" class="submit3" onclick="return checknull()" tabindex="4">
```

The button does not have an id attribute. How do I select and click it using JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean by how to click a button if does not have id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('input.submit3[type=submit]').click();
```

Plain JavaScript (requires `querySelector` as [defined by W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/)):

```
document.querySelector('input.submit3[type=submit]').click();
```

Comment: @gskishan004 Just click the green tick next to the answer :)